# Determining maximal ideals of a quotient polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field and consider the quotient of the ring of polynomials in $X$ and $Y$ over $K$ by the ideal generated by $XY$:

$$R:=K[X,Y]/(XY)$$

I have to find the maximal ideals of such $R$. I know the correspondence between (maximal) ideals of $K[X,Y]$, that are all finitely generated, which contain $(XY)$ and (maximal) ideals of $R$ as it is a quotient ring however I'm not sure on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Take a look at this question for an idea of how to approach your problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252832/maximal-ideals-in-mathbbrx-y-xy-2?rq=1

Comment: Also as hinted at in the answer below, we know from algebraic geometry that the maximal ideals of $K[X,Y]/(XY)$ correspond to closed point of the non-reduced scheme/topological space $\mathrm{Spec}(K[X,Y]/(XY))$, which can be thought of as the coordinate axes in $\mathbb{A}^2_K$. If this confuses more than it helps just ignore it.

Comment: Actually the maximal ideals are of the form $(X,f(Y))$, respectively $(g(X),Y)$ with $f, g$ irreducible. In order to show this notice that every maximal ideal contains $X$ or $Y$. The (maximal) ideals containing $X$ correspond to the (maximal) ideals of $K[X,Y]/(X)\simeq K[Y]$.

Answer (score -2):

If K is algebraically closed the maximal ideals correspond to points on the axes, So they are $$\{(X, Y-a)~|~ a \in K\} \cup \{(X-a, Y)~|~ a \in K\}$$

When K not algebraically closed the answer is messy

Comment: Isn't messy at all; your case follows easily from the general case I pointed out in a comment under the question.